# Definition of surface integration in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I want to know the definition of surface integration:

$$\int_{\partial B(x_0,r)} u dS$$

where $u:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$.

How is related to $\int_{B(x_0,r)} u(x) dx$ ?

Answer (score 1):

You know the integral over the boundary tells you nothing about the integral over the interior without any restrictions on $u$ - if you fix the values of $u$ on the boundary, you can choose essentially any values for it on the interior.  There is a similar looking relationship though called Stokes' theorem.

For integration, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere#Spherical_coordinates.  They give the n-1-sphere's volume element as

$d_{S^{n-1}}V = \sin^{n-2}(\phi_1)\sin^{n-3}(\phi_2)\cdots \sin(\phi_{n-2})\, d\phi_1 \, d\phi_2\cdots d\phi_{n-1}$.  (See the wikipedia page for exact formula)

You would write your function $u$ in terms of these spherical coordinates $r, \phi_1,...,\phi_{n-1}$, tack on this volume element $d_{S^{n-1}}V$ and integrate for $\phi_{n-1}$ from 0 to $2\pi$ and the rest of the $\phi$ from 0 to $\pi$.

That is, the integral over the n-1-sphere of u is $\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^\pi...\int_0^\pi u(r,\phi_1,...,\phi_{n-1})d_{S^{n-1}}V$.